# how to enable TLS and https requests for a website using node.js and express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, https, tls1.2

I'm doing one of my first projects of web programming using node.js (using express.js) as back and react as front. Some requests to my node server need to be secure like post requests for sending login and register data.
what should i do?
is there any library for node or react to help me?
and which parts of my project should i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways:

1. Enable https at node express level. Use some tutorial like this
   https://medium.com/@nileshsingh/everything-about-creating-an-https-server-using-node-js-2fc5c48a8d4e
2. Or put node server behind nginx reverse proxy. This way actually is easier for beginner. Simple nginx configuration + certbot and it is done. Certbot is a tool that will provide you free certificates and integrate them into your nginx configuration - https://certbot.eff.org/